# compare two json and Add new object in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I will store json data in localstorage, program loading time compare the local storage json and variable declared json. If both are different, add that to localstorage json.

I have tried like below

```
var intial_json_string='{'+
    ' "javascript":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "html":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "php":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "java":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "Bottel":{"totmark":0,"outof":100}'+
    '}';

function first_load()
{
    var tmp_json=jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("localconst_json"));
    var loc_tmp_json=jQuery.parseJSON(intial_json_string);

    var temp_obj={"totmark":0,"outof":100};

    $.grep(tmp_json,function(n,i){
        var found=0;
        $.grep(loc_tmp_json,function(n1,i1){    

            if(n==n1)
                found=1;
        });
        if(found==1)
        {
            loc_tmp_json[n] = temp_obj;
        }
    });
}
```

Example

```
var json1='{'+
    ' "javascript":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "html":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "php":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "java":{"totmark":0,"outof":100},'+
    ' "Bottel":{"totmark":0,"outof":100}'+
    '}';

var json2='{'+
    ' "javascript":{"totmark":1,"outof":100},'+
    ' "html":{"totmark":2,"outof":100},'+
    ' "php":{"totmark":3,"outof":100},'+
    ' "java":{"totmark":5,"outof":100}'+
    '}';
```

Compare both json objects and if not existing then add the missing object to json2.

```
var json2='{'+
    ' "javascript":{"totmark":1,"outof":100},'+
    ' "html":{"totmark":2,"outof":100},'+
    ' "php":{"totmark":3,"outof":100},'+
    ' "java":{"totmark":5,"outof":100},'+
    ' "Bottel":{"totmark":0,"outof":100}'+
    '}';
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: check this for 2 json object comparisonhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: I can compare, how can I add the object to json

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

this should help

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp_json=jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("localconst_json"));
var loc_tmp_json=jQuery.parseJSON(intial_json_string);

var temp_obj={"totmark":0,"outof":100};


$.each(loc_tmp_json,function(n,i){
    var found=0;
    $.each(tmp_json,function(n1,i1){    

        if(n==n1)
            found=1;
    });
    if(found==0)
    {
        tmp_json[n] = temp_obj;
    }
});


localStorage.setItem("localconst_json",JSON.stringify(tmp_json));
const_json=jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("localconst_json"));
```